# Query() function in Google Sheets yields stray value: Why, and how can I fix it?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I would like to run a query statement that adds a bullet (●) to each row of output.

Here is my sample data:

[image]

Here is the query:

=query($A$1:$B$3,"SELECT '●',A,B",0)

Here is the result:

[image]

Why does the first stray line appear in the output ["●"()], and how can I write the query so that it yields only rows 2, 3, 4 and not the first row?

Note that the actual data is much more complicated than this, so solving it with a filter or array does not work well. I need a query solution. And I'd really like to know why that first line is appearing in the first place.

Thanks for the help.

KLS

Comment: At a guess, I'd say that the additional row is being added as a way to label the column that isn't a data column from your source range, and that maybe it's added the `()` because it's naively interpreting it as an empty query function.

For example, see what this query yields
`=QUERY($A$1:$B$3, "SELECT TRUE, '•', 2",0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY($A$1:$B$3, "SELECT '●', A, B LABEL '●' ''", 0)
```

This assigns an empty string to the [label](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#label) for that column, thus eliminating the label row.

Comment: Thanks, Clay. Interesting. The column suppression parameter 0 only applies to the table data and not to any columns I add to the output. Very helpful.

Comment: That 0 as the last optional parameter notes how many rows, starting with the first, of your data range contain headers, and you're correct, it only applies to the original data itself.